# python recommended way for exiting program

Tags: python, exit

This is a very basic design question. My program needs to exit if some conditions are not satisfied. I have a  `class A`. The method `main_logic` shown below has the controlling instructions.  This method  creates several instances and calls some methods defined on those. I am showing one such example, where it creates object `b = CalcB()` and then calls b.run().

While in `b.run()`, I am conditionally exiting the code in `update_val` . The `main_logic` is responsible for calling other code as well.

**My questions are** :

1. Is it an acceptable practice to exit program from some supporting code (in this case the `update_val` of `CalcB`?   Or should I always return some error code and do this inside main_logic?
2. Is there a better design to handle such situation? Example some error handling class? any illustration of elegant solution would be appreciated

   ```
   import sys
   class Shelf:
      def get_factor(self):
          self.some_factor = 0.5
          return self.some_factor

   class CalcB:
      def __init__(self):
          self.shelf = Shelf()
          self.ref = 1.0
          self.area = 3.14285

      def run(self):
          print("Calculation B running")
          some_factor = self.shelf.get_factor()
          self.update_val(some_factor)

      def update_val(self, some_factor):
          self.value = some_factor*self.area
          if (self.value > self.ref):
              print("too bad.. exiting the program")
              sys.exit() 

   class A: 
      def main_logic(self):
          b = CalcB()
          b.run()
          # some more code follows...
          #do_something()
          #d = CalcD()
          #do_something_else(d)                       

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       a = A()
       a.main_logic()
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code to be reusable, it should not force the behavior of the calling code. A standard solution is to raise an exception, and have your main program exit on that exception.

```
class ClassAException(Exception):
    pass

class ClassA (object):
    def method:
        if situation not in stuff_I_can_handle:
            raise ClassAException('Cannot handle ' +repr(situation))
```

I am not sure about your second question. A situation you know how to handle should probably be handled there and then. Exceptions are for situations you are not prepared to handle.

Comment: thanks @tripleee and Antti . So would you suggest creating a custom exception class ? Also, could you answer the second part of the question... i.e. should I have some common class to observe such problems and raise exception?